# Is it undefined still undefined?

Tags: javascript, undefined, javascript-objects

I saw in old answer in the stackoverflow and across the Web that 'undefined' can be assigned.
I remember that is can be assigned. But I think not more.

So when I open console and try to do
`undefined = 'value'; console.log (undefined);`
I get undefined as the output.

Are browsers have a new handling about undefined?

Comment: Could you provide a reference/link to the answer you are referring to?

Comment: From the first answer of the possible duplicate: "ECMAScript 5 changed this behavior, and now the property is not writable nor configurable. Therefore, assignments to undefined will be ignored in non-strict mode, and will throw an exception is strict mode."

Comment: here: http://jsbin.com/behapod/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In strict mode, `undefined` can't be redefined.